# How Could i refer an objective c file part of a pod inside a Swift CocoaPods Project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I have created a CocoaPods Project with 'pod lib create 'someProject'' command. The File structure of which is following.
[image: File Structure]

The "Development Pods contains Assets and classes that i want to host on cocoapods master, but, it's dependent on a third party pods written in objective c". The problem is that the objective-c header does not have visibility in the folder structure "Development Pods". Bridging header cannot be created to use objective c file in swift project as it's a framework. Also, the header cannot be included in module map files as it is part of a pod, but not the actual file structure.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Does your pod have the other pod written in Objective-C listed as a dependency in its .podspec file?

Comment: I have not yet published the pod, but yeah, the dependency is mentioned.